# Python - imported a excel trying to call 2 columns of data where data is pulled from column 1 if matched in column 2

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to python and scripting in general. so if this seems simple I am sorry. I have tried to google etc but not finding what I am after.

- Issue
  I have a excel sheet that I import

```
import pandas as pd
path_input = r'C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\List.xlsx
```

From this I can then pull and print any column I like for example below

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_input)
fqdn = list(df.FQDN)
owner = list(df.Owner)
```

what I would like to do is only call data where cells in column fqdn is equal to a certain name in  column owner.

so that I can then use the fqdn data to eventually run code to login to the devices.

Any help is really appreciated.

example would be pulling

```
    fqdn             owner
abc.example.com      David
cde.example.com      David
```

Answered - I ended up doing a combination of suggestions but I found this worked for me.

'''
new_df = df[df.Owner == 'Name']
new_df1 = new_df.iloc[0:87, 0:1]

Comment: I think you are looking for this, `df[df['fqdn']==df['owner']]`?

Comment: After the edit i am a bit confused. Could you share sample input and expected output?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah haven't really added anything just formatted

Comment: @Himanshuman - That's true, when I first look at the unedited version I thought he is looking for fqdn and owner where the values are common. `fqdn is equal to a certain name in column owner.` This part needs clarification.

Comment: Thank you Mohamed but how would I add the variable to match the 'owner' to a name?

Comment: TRy this, `df[df['fqdn']=='name']` or `df[df['fqdn'].isin(['name1', 'name2'])]`. Please have a look at @RJAdriaansen's suggested post.

Comment: Thank you all. I am just looking at the post suggested by @RJAdriaansen

Answer (score 0):

What I understood you actually want to call cells in column owner that are equal to a certain name in column owner, not vice versa.

You may not be able to directly call the data that satisfies the condition you want, but you can easily edit the dataframe after calling. So,

```
new_df = df[df.OWNER == CERTAIN_NAME]
```

would return the rows where owner names are equal to a given name.

Comment: Thank you, I used your suggestion and it worked nearly as I wanted. however I would like to reduce it slightly more

My code is currently now 

from datetime import date
from shutil import copyfile
import pandas as pd

date_backup = date.today()
print(date_backup)
str_date_backup = str(date_backup)

path_input = r'C:\Users\x\Projects\x\List.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path_input)
first_column = df[df.columns[0]]
new_df = df[df.Owner == 'Name']

print(new_df)

How do I get it to just pull column 0 instead of the whole sheet.